# how to develop N-Tier Layer for WCF Service by using Entity framework 6.0.. Suggest me exposing Entities as datacontract is good or bad?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-5

Could you please help in creating N-Tier Arch for WCF Service which will uses Entity framework 6.0 for data access.

I have worked in Creating N-Tier Arch for WCF using Software factory with Enterprise library....for data access and exception logging in database as well as in file system

But am really confused whether I can expose the Entities which generated as part of the Entity framework in the WCF Service data contract... also suggest me how to implement other activities like exception logging in database using the entity framework...

If possible please guide me by creating Sample or demo N-TIER Arch for WCF using Entity framework...

I have seen lot of articles saying need to use repository pattern when using Entity framework

Do we really need to implement or use repository pattern when using Entity framework
Is using Trackable Entities a good idea for WCF? Also please explain how the Trackable Entities works?

Answer (score 1):

[This blog](http://blog.trivadis.com/b/christofsenn/archive/2013/07/18/distributed-domain-layer.aspx) is not only about exposing entities via WCF but also about implementing business logic as part of those entities and sharing it via shared assemblies on .NET clients and servers.

Concerning n-tier architecture and respective implementation you may well be interested in using the **[N-Tier Entity Framework](https://ntieref.codeplex.com/)** which perfectly addresses your needs. The framework provides Visual Studio templates to create required components for the different tiers. Then it provides T4 code generation templates to generate client and server code based on entity models (edmx). You may also find sample applications and a [user guide](https://ntieref.codeplex.com/releases/view/102841) for download on codeplex.

Logging exceptions and other information is done best using a logging framework like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). If you need to send log messages from client to server you should do so using async messaging which can be done with WCF using MSMQ binding.